# Capture data sent to/from a browser window

Tags: javascript, http, browser

I'm trying to capture data from a poker gaming site. The game is played through a new browser window, and I'd like to somehow "record" any/all data going to and from the browser. Eventually I'd like to parse the data for analysis and statistics, to create a "tool" of sorts to help newbie players.

But my first step in this challenge is to be able to capture the data transferred to/from the browser.

Anyone have any ideas on how to capture this?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: You mean something like Sharkscope and the like? Thats' illegal anyway, and those transaction are pretty secure, very hard to intercept (there are real money on the stake, and poker gaming site biggest problem are cheater who could intercept data like money, cards dealt, and so on). Avoid sniffing is among poker (and casino) gaming sites' top priorities

Comment: Not quite. I'm not looking to mine data that isn't sent to the browser (ie: players history, credit cards, etc). I'm just trying to capture the data that tells the browser that Player1 raised 20, Player 2 folded, your hand has pocket 2's, it's Player3's call, etc.. I'm just trying to catch the data the browser is already displaying to the user.

Comment: You can use Wireshark to capture the traffic sent over the network. You can also use Firebug or Developer Tools to see the contents of AJAX transactions.

Comment: To be totally clear: You're on the client-side of things and want to grab all of the data going to and from another site?

Comment: You'll probably need to use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools. However, most sites of the kind you've mentioned use obfuscation and encryption heavily in order to prevent automation. Can you share a link to a sample site so we can see the kind of data going through?

Answer (score 0):

Use wireshark to capture outgoing connection if connection is not encrypt with https